# I'm doing dictation I want to know what they are saying

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, listening

[Birds of Prey interview](https://youtu.be/5-aroTh5cME?t=20)

in this video at 0:21, what is he saying? To me, it sounds like "It's so _______ awful"

and at 2:15 Is she saying "she will? would? just bash it"?

and I really don't know what he's saying at 2:24... all I hear is.. "and I just got... blah blah.."

please help me

Comment: If I am getting the parts you are asking about correct, you have at 0:19 "It's good that you are in London where it's cold and rainy and horrible all the time" but the second one is really hard to hear, even at 25% playback speed; "... put an impression?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0:19 - "It's good that you are in London where it's cold and rainy and horrible all the time - it's worked out so well for you"

2:15 - "(S)he(?) would just be.... god, she'd drive him insane"...

2:24 - "And I just got a Harlequin impression" (Harlequin is a character previously played by Robbie)